# Windows 10 File Explorer: Search in indexed locations include compressed archives

Tags: windows-10

I use Windows 10 File Explorer and I want to search in indexed locations include compressed archives (zip).
In File Explorer folder settings there is only "when searching non-indexed locations" > "include compressed archives"...
Please, can you help me how to do it?
Thanks,
Jiri

Answer (score 0):

**Go To Index Option You can Find in Control Panel(View as Small icon).**

See the below Snapshot

1. Go to ***Advance*** Option

[image]

2. Go to ***File type*** Tab --> Check for Extension to be Indexed (Select .Zip)
3. Select ***Index Properties and File Content***. You can even add Different extension if which is not available in list. --> Click on ***OK*** wait for while till the index get complete. (It may take more time depends on the File/Location/size)

[image]

Comment: This are exactly my settings. But when I search in File Explorer (for example) for *.txt in folder which content is .zip archive too, then it doesn't show me list of *.txt files which are in .zip archive...

Comment: Did the index completed. For testing purpose create a text or document make it zip. Put in one folder. Go to file explorer to the same folder try to search in .txt. if it fetching from zip. I think the indexing is not completed

Comment: @JiříPoláček, please take a few minutes to read the question that I referenced as a duplicate, including the subsequent comments below the accepted answer.  To utilize your example, the bottom line is that when you search for a `.txt` document within a `.zip` file, the search results will show you the zip files themselves and *not* the txt documents.  This is by design, because the text files are essentially the contents of the zip files.

Comment: OK, now I see. But is this only the way indexing works or it is general? Maybe - if I don't index the location and set "when searching non-indexed locations" > "include compressed archives", will it work?

Comment: @Techie Gossip yes, indexing of that folder is completed, I checked it before

Comment: @JiříPoláček, no, unfortunately it will work the same way and your search results will take *much* longer to appear.  That is simply the way that the Windows search function works, essentially because a Zip archive is a file and not a folder.